# Remove small values from matrix

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `(n, m)` tensor `X` where I want to zero out all values smaller than some threshold `t`. I.e.,

```
X = X * tf.cast(tf.greater(X, t), X.dtype)
```

I was wondering, is there a more efficient way to do this? Because `X` in my setup is huge and as I understand it, the `tf.cast(tf.greater(X, t), X.dtype)` constructs an other tensor that needs as much memory as `X`.

Comment: Have you tried using the `eval` method in tensorflow to transform your tensor into a numpy array and then use one of the answers below?

Comment: I'm just brainstorming here, `tf.add` and `tf.subtract` support broadcasting, so they should be memory efficient. Can you maybe try subtract `t`, then do `tf.clip_by_value(...)` then add `t` back? Intuitively it results in more operations, but less memory usage?

Comment: @RobertLacok Thanks for the input but that is not the same I think. by adding back `t` you replace zeros with `t`

Comment: I feel shamefully stupid right now

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with the good old

```
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(m):
      if X[n][m] < t: X[n][m] = 0
```

Comment: It's in tensorflow

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will more efficient

```
x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
y = tf.where(tf.greater(x, tf.constant(5)),
             x, # if ture
             tf.zeros_like(x)) # if false

with tf.Session() as sess:
    a = sess.run(y)
    # a is [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

If X is your matrix (a numpy array I assume) you can try:

```
x[x<small_value]=0
```

if creating the boolean array takes too much memory you can try doing that through a loop by individual columns.

Comment: It's in tensorflow. Should have made this more clear from the question, but the tag was there :)

Comment: Oh sorry, no idea then, I have never used them

Answer (score 0):

```
foo = tf.constant([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10.])
threshold_map = tf.greater(foo, tf.constant(5.))
threshold_map_index = tf.reshape(tf.where(threshold_map), [-1])
foo_threshold = tf.gather(foo, threshold_map_index)
# foo_threshold = [6., 7., 8., 9., 10.]
```

( this **won't** work with more then one-dimension )